# Generic code generation in Java

Tags: java, swing, generics

I am learning Java (and Swing), and am developing a small code generator that generates Java classes after asking you some information.

The first window asks the class **name** (mandatory), **mother-class name**, and asks if you wish to generate a default constructor. Once you press Generate, a `JDialog` opens up with the generated class.

But my issue comes to the generic side of my code generation.

Once the information about the class is saved, I call my `generateCode` function that looks like such:

```
private String generateCode(Information info) {
    String code = "";

    // info contains all the information inputed by the user
    if (info.motherClass.equals("") && info.generateDefaultConstructor == false) {
        code = "public class " + info.name + "{\n\n}";
    } else {

    }
    return code;
}
```

As you can see, I only handle the case where only the class name is given.

How should I code it in order to handle other options? Should it be with a block of conditions handling everything one by one? I truly want to make my code as generic as possible in order to add more features later on.

Thank you.

Comment: "I truly want to make my code as generic as possible in order to add more features later on." [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI).

Comment: I did not know of this saying, I giggled. You are absolutely right, but I'm trying to learn generic coding as well, so see it as a lesson.

Comment: Code can be made infinitely generic and customizable, at the expense of usability (and performance). You have to decide upon the use case you want to support before you can start making code generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend making all the none static fields of `Information` `private` or `protected` add `getters` and `setters`.

Then add a few methods that can check and / or manipulate `Strings` like:

```
public static String removeSpaces(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return "";
    }
    String enter = (char) (13) + (char) (10) + "";
    String tab = (char) (9) + "";
    String space = (char) (32) + "";
    String empty = "";
    return input.replace(enter, empty).replace(tab, empty).replace(space, empty);
}

public static String newLine(){
  return (char) (13) + (char) (10) + "";
}

public static String tab(){
  return (char) (9) + "";
}
```

Then split the generateCode method into something like:

```
private String generateCode(Information info) {
  StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
  code.append(getClassCode(info.getMotherClass()));
  code.append(newLine());
  code.append(tab());
  code.append(getConstructor(info));
  return code.toString();
}

public static String getClassCode(String className){
  StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
  code.append("public class ");
  if (!removeSpaces(className).isEmpty()){
    code.append(className);  
  } else {
    code.append(Information.getDefaultClass());//have a default static name for a class like "Application"
  }
  code.append("{");
  code.append(newLine());
  return code.toString();
}

public static String getConstructor(Information info){
  StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
  if(!info.isGenerateDefaultConstructor()) {
    code.append("public ");
    code.append(info.getMotherClass());
    code.append("(){");
    code.append(newLine());
    code.append(tab());
    code.append(info.getConstructorContent());//what will be in the constructor
    code.append(newLine());
    code.append(tab());
    code.append("}");
  }
  code.append(newLine());
  return code.toString();
}
```

And then you can keep going by adding bits and pieces here and there.

Answer (score 0):

You could make info as a string list and iterate through it skipping code generation where the list is an empty string.